# Вывод данных в графический интерфейc tkinker Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть программа, которая выводит на печать раз в секунду список из 30 значений (имитация значений с датчиков). Для нее написан небольшой графический интерфейс на tkinker. При запуске программы открывается окно, при нажатии на кнопку Старт, в окно для текста раз в секунду печатается строка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать кнопку Стоп, останавливающую печать. При этом весь напечатанный текст должен остаться в окне и при нажатии на кнопку Пуск печать должна продолжиться.

```
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from utils import register_to_list
from time import sleep
import random
from datetime import datetime
from constants import CHOICES

registers_list = []

flag = True

def print_reg_values(registers_list, txt, window):
    """Пока значение flag истинно, каждую секунду выводит на печать
    данные с датчиков и записывает эти данные в список.
    Возвращает список из списков, содержащих данные с датчиков на каждую секунду
    """
    global flag
    while flag:
        numbers = []
        for i in range(15):
            numbers.append(random.choice(CHOICES))
        values = register_to_list(numbers)
        txt.insert(1.0, f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} {values}\n')
        window.update()
        registers_list.append((datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), values))
        sleep(1)

window = Tk()  
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение PythonRu")  
window.geometry('1200x800')  

start = Button(window, text="Старт", width=13, height=2, command=lambda: print_reg_values(registers_list, txt, window))  
start.grid(column=0, row=0)
stop = Button(window, text="Стоп", width=13, height=2)  
stop.grid(column=0, row=1)

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=160, height=10)  
txt.grid(column=1, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

[image: Пример окна с печатью текста]

Comment: Ну у вас практически все готово. Просто добавьте функцию для кнопки stop, в которой значение в переменной flag на False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from utils import register_to_list
from time import sleep
import random
from datetime import datetime
from constants import CHOICES

registers_list = []

flag = True
def stop_func():
    global flag
    flag = False

def print_reg_values(registers_list, txt, window):
    """Пока значение flag истинно, каждую секунду выводит на печать
    данные с датчиков и записывает эти данные в список.
    Возвращает список из списков, содержащих данные с датчиков на каждую секунду
    """
    global flag
    while flag:
        numbers = []
        for i in range(15):
            numbers.append(random.choice(CHOICES))
        values = register_to_list(numbers)
        txt.insert(1.0, f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} {values}\n')
        window.update()
        registers_list.append((datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), values))
        sleep(1)

window = Tk()  
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение PythonRu")  
window.geometry('1200x800')  

start = Button(window, text="Старт", width=13, height=2, command=lambda: print_reg_values(registers_list, txt, window))  
start.grid(column=0, row=0)
stop = Button(window, text="Стоп", width=13, height=2, command = stop_func)  
stop.grid(column=0, row=1)

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=160, height=10)  
txt.grid(column=1, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```